# Does if ... else work with arrays and matrixes?

Tags: r

```
aa <- seq(1, 10, 1)
bb <- a * runif(n = 10, min = 0, max = 2) * 1000
cc <- cbind(aa, bb)

dd <- ifelse(aa / bb - 1 > .1, cc, cc * 10)
```

How may I do `ifelse` returns a matrix like `cc` instead of a column array?

I tried `if` and `else` like

```
aa <- seq(1, 10, 1)
bb <- a * runif(n = 10, min = 0, max = 2) * 1000
cc <- cbind(aa, bb)

if(aa / bb - 1 > .1) {
    cc
}
else {
    cc * 10
}
```

Two issues: the 1st one is that it just uses the first element, but I guess I can solve it by using a `for()` cycle; the 2nd one is that it returns

```
Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try putting `else` on the same line as the closing `}` for `if`. Also, in `bb`, do you mean `aa * runif...`?

Answer (score 0):

The function `ifelse()` is equally happy to accept vectors and matrices.  Adapting your example slightly:

```
ifelse(cc > 1000, -cc, cc * 10)
       aa          bb
 [1,]  10   2006.2160
 [2,]  20  -3636.6234
 [3,]  30    455.8483
 [4,]  40  -4939.6886
 [5,]  50  -3519.1552
 [6,]  60  -1359.0747
 [7,]  70  -2267.0220
 [8,]  80  -9232.1221
 [9,]  90  -5942.5760
[10,] 100 -19439.4255
```

The reason this works is that arrays and matrices are in fact vectors with some additional attributes that defines the number or rows and columns.

The point about `ifelse` is that your input and output should have the same number of elements.

Comment: What does it mean when, using `if` statement, you obtain `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`?

Comment: @user1611518 `if` is a different function that accepts only a single scalar (i.e. one element) as input.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to deal with arrays and non matchable dimensions?

Comment: @user1611518 I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: May you tell me what do I have to input in order to obtain the help for `if` command? `?if` is not accepted.

Comment: Thank you. While I was examining my code, I concluded the problem was some NA in the array/matrix. Reading `if` help, it confirms the function does not deal with NAs. Then I had to replace each NA with 0 in order to make `if` works properly.

Answer (score 0):

If would try something like this:

```
sel <- aa / bb - 1 > .1
cc[sel, ] <- 10 * cc[sel,]
```

Comment: Then you're suggesting array indexing may substitute `if` statement... I have to try, I'll let you know if it does work :)